# Hashset Equality override for structs containing reference type

Tags: c#, struct, copy, hashset

I am trying to implement struct containing state of a board game, so I need multiple states of a game in a HashSet.

Data part looks like this:

```
struct Sokoban
{

    public List<List<char>> data;   // data matrix
    public int sx, sy;              // sokoban's position
    public int bx, by;              // box position
    public int cx, cy;              // final box position
```

As struct are value types, when I create new instance with:

```
Sokoban nextState = actualState;
```

where actualState is a formerly initialized instance,
it should copy all fields of `actualState` to `nextState`.
So `nextState` and `actualState` now points to the same List>.  .
My question is, how can have a proper copy of this struct?
If I create a constructor like:

```
public Sokoban(Sokoban originalSokoban)          
    {

        this.sx = originalSokoban.sx;
        this.sy = originalSokoban.sy;
        this.bx = originalSokoban.bx;
        this.by = originalSokoban.by;
        this.cx = originalSokoban.cx;
        this.cy = originalSokoban.cy;


        List<List<char>> data2 = new List<List<char>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < originalSokoban.data.Count(); i++)
        {

            data2.Add( new List<char>(originalSokoban.data[i]));
        }
        this.data = data2;
     }
```

it works.
But, when I add these two distinct instances to hashset they are not recognized as same. This is my code for overriden GetHashCode,Equals, ==, != operators :

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (( sx+sy+bx+by+ cx+ cy).GetHashCode()+(data).GetHashCode());
    }          

    public static bool operator ==(Sokoban x, Sokoban y)
    {
        bool isEqual = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.data.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < x.data[0].Count(); j++)
            {
                if (x.data[i][j] != y.data[i][j])
                {
                    isEqual = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return isEqual &&
        x.sx == y.sx &&
        x.sy == y.sy &&
        x.bx == y.bx &&
        x.by == y.by &&
        x.cx == y.cx &&
        x.cy == y.cy;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Sokoban x, Sokoban y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
         return obj is Sokoban && this == (Sokoban)obj;       
    }
```

I don't know where I'm making mistake, if you have any comments or remarks I'll gladly accept any help, I'm stuck with this for 3 days, thank you :)

Comment: That type almost certainly shouldn't be a `struct`.  It's mutable, it's rather large, it doesn't represent a single logical value, etc.  It should be a class.

Comment: if there should be the same `(data).GetHashCode()` should return the same for both instances, which is not possible as they are 2 distinct instances of the list, that happen to have the same content. But `GetHashCode` of `List<T>` does not take in account that.  So you r resulting hashcode, may result in always different number for the same instances of struct.

Comment: I tried 'class' in the first place, but I couldn't make functional constructor which would make DEEP copy of the board, it still referenced to the same `List<List<char>>`

Comment: @martinerk0 That task is going to be unaffected by whether the type is a value type or a reference type.

Comment: What is the nature of the data matrix?  Will the reference change during the life of the structure?  What about the content identified thereby?  How big will it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking on the code, most likely the problem is here

```
 public override int GetHashCode()
 {
   //(data).GetHashCode() !!! List<T>::GetHashCode()..
   return (( sx+sy+bx+by+ cx+ cy).GetHashCode()+(data).GetHashCode());
 }
```

`data.GetHashCode()` is unique for every new instance of the struct, so your resulting `GetHashCode()` may result in totally different number for instances that are supposed to be equal according to your logic.  Change your `GetHashCode()` method to meet your needs.